# selenium test case for facebook login and if doesn't login then automatically enter create new account option i cant automate theCreatenewAccount opt

Tags: java, selenium, facebook

selenium test case for facebook login and if doesn't login then automatically enter create new account option and i tried to search the locators in the HTML code for create new account option there id and class use these as a findelement(by.class) it doesn't works and shown NoSuchElementFound Exception in console window

```java
package com.Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Login_site {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\Selenium\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();

        wd.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        wd.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("hansiflick@gmail.com");

        wd.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("whfhwh");

        wd.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        wd.findelement(by. 
    ---- //i've given id, name, class everything and still shows NoSuchElementFoundException and doesn't automate the create new account button

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To login into [*Facebook*](https://www.facebook.com/) using a valid set of credentials, you can use the following code block:

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#email")).sendKeys("hansiflick@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='pass']")).sendKeys("whfhwh");
```